# Is there a way reach to grandchild count with related name in django?

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-views, django-templates

I have several models like that;

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

class SurveyCollector(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='survey_collector_survey')

class SurveyResponse(models.Model):
    collector = models.ForeignKey(SurveyCollector, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='surveyresponse_collector')
```

and i would like to display survey responses count in the survey_list.html. My template code seems like that;

```
{% for survey in surveys %}
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ survey.name }}</th>
    <td align="center">{{ survey.survey_collector_survey.count }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I can get surveys collectors with above code. But i cannot get true result when i try this code

```
<td align="center">{{ survey.survey_collector_survey.surveyresponse_collector.count }}</td>
```

I couldnt find right approach. Could you please help me to find the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to that in such a way, since you here will eventually have an *N+1* problem: you will make *N+1* queries to the database: one query to fetch all the surveys, and *N* extra queries to fetch all the `SurveyCollector`s. If you count grandchildren, it will even be worse.

You can simply *annotate* your queryset, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def some_view(request):
    surveys = Survey.objects.annotate(
        nresponse=Count('survey_collector_survey__surveyresponse_collector')
    )
    # …
    return render(request, 'some_template.html',{'surveys': surveys})
```

Now the `Survey` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.nresponse` that you can then use when rendering the template:

```
{% for survey in surveys %}
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ survey.name }}</th>
    <td align="center">{{ survey.nresponse }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot Willem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a property in your Survey model.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = ............

    @property
    def response_count(self):
        return SurveyResponse.objects.filter(collector__survey__pk = self.pk).aggregate(Count('collector'))['collector__count']

class SurveyCollector(models.Model):
    survey = ..........

class SurveyResponse(models.Model):
    collector = ...........
```

Now in your templates, you can directly use this property.

```
<td align="center">{{ survey.response }}</td>
```

Note: Take care of the [double underscores (__)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)